# Downloading Google Sheet as CSV only downloads first sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, export-to-csv

Trying to download Google sheet as CSV in such a way as to keep the formatting of timestamps

I can do this with the following gas script.

But it only downloads the first sheet.

I want to be able to declare the sheet to download

How to do this?

gas

```
function autoDownload() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('download');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'CSV download dialog');
  Utilities.sleep(9000);
}

function saveAsCSV() {
  let ss     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      ssname = "sumApp-Headers",
      sheet  = ss.getSheetByName("Elements");

  var folder ="1KivXXXXfW3"  // DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
  var fileName = ssname + ".csv";
  var params = ss.getId() +  "/export?exportFormat=csv&format=csv";
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + params;  
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  
  console.log(url)
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + sheet.getSheetId(), {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  url = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder)
              .createFile(ssname, response, MimeType.CSV)
              .getDownloadUrl();
              //.replace("?e=download&gd=true","");         
    return url;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  Auto Download CSV ... please wait
</body>
<script>
  function executeDownload(url) {
      window.location.href = url;
  }
  window.onload=function() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(executeDownload)
      .saveAsCSV();
    window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9000);
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `I want to be able to declare the sheet to download`, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + sheet.getSheetId(), {
```

#### To:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "&gid=" + sheet.getSheetId(), {
```

- By this, the sheet given by `sheet  = ss.getSheetByName("Elements");` is used.

Comment: Tanaike, thank you!  That fix it